# Confusion about the support of Node.js by hosting providers

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm working for a small company on something like a new PHP environment for future projects. I'd like to cram in as much modernization and automization as possible (while I can).

The thing is, I always come across solutions that require Node.js (Grunt, Autoprefixer, ...). None of our customer's hosting providers support Node.js (not even our own managed server). Most of the time I don't even have shell access.

I come across `npm this` and `npm that` so often, almost as if it's some always available quasistandard. Do I have some misunderstanding here – or is this simply only usable by people hosting their projects on their own servers? Am I just out of luck if I have to support a wide range of (sometimes questionable) shared hosting providers?

Comment: PHP has been around longer so it has more hosting options... you should still be able to find a decent amount of Node hosting providers (Heroku, Nodejitsu, Joyent)

Comment: Your PS was really a *second* question so I've removed it. Also, that PS was asking for a library recommendation, which would make your question worthy of being closed.

Comment: NPM is a package manager. It originated in node.js, but is now quite often used for projects that don't rely on node. For example, I am just starting a new project that uses Angular.js and Firebase. I need npm (and consequently node) on my local machine to pull down packages and build the project, but after that I can deploy on any host.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In my case that would mean I would have to upload my  locally generated asset cache and turn off the asset manager and just link the cached files in my template. Seems to me a little too hackish to me.

Comment: @tymeJV My problem is that I can't decide where the projects will be hosted.

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to: Can I use things that depend on Node on hosting providers that neither provide Node or allow me to install it? I would have thought that was a no.

Comment: "is this simply only usable by people hosting their projects on their own servers". Yes but not necessarily actual physical servers, this can be a cheap virtualised server, or using something like Docker where the host OS doesn't need any configuring.

Comment: @MattHarrison Yeah, that is my question. It's stupid, but it feels odd that all these nice tools are completely unusable if your stuck with shared hosting (which I would think isn't that uncommon for small businesses with lots of penny-pinching customers). I guess I have to do without Autoprefixer. :-(

Comment: @Steffen There's always: http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

Comment: @MattHarrison Louis removed my PS where I mentioned -prefix-free. I'd like to have something that integrates with my server-side asset management. I might give it a try now though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing *most* PHP applications and *most* Node.js applications is apples and oranges.

Most PHP applications are fairly self-contained and intended to be used with web servers and a mostly stock PHP configuration.  Most Node.js applications have a ton of NPM dependencies that need to be installed, and while HTTP is used to connect between the web server and the Node.js application, it isn't always clear what port that will be on.  Plus, the Node.js application may require extra configuration, command line parameters, etc.  Some hosting for Node.js is smart enough to look at the package.json file (Elastic Beanstalk for example) and figure out how to start your Node.js application.

These days you will find PHP going the same way.  A lot of software is built with Composer packages that must be set up and installed.  You won't find many folks getting that working on shared hosting either.  Many Node.js applications have nothing to do with the web or web servers.  That is increasingly becoming the case with PHP as well, but you won't find shared hosting for PHP applications.

Basically, you're looking at two entirely different ecosystems.

I think that your company needs to realize that you're sacrificing an awful lot just to stay compatible with cheap crappy shared hosting.  These days you can get a $5/mo. VPS to run whatever you want, and that's often the same price as your shared hosting.  Why waste time and resources while building a substandard application if you can pay $10 more a year and do what you want/need to do?

Use the technologies that you need to get the job done.  If what you can do works fine in a normal PHP web application framework, then use that.  If you need to build a persistent server application and feel that Node.js is right for you, use that.

Comment: Uhm, thanks, but I wasn't comparing Node.js and PHP. And we're not trying to stay compatible with shared hosting, but with our customers.  If I could I would just require our customers to use a server managed by me, but that's not how it works.

Comment: @Steffen You asked why things were the way they were, I explained, and gave you a viable option for pushing forward.  If that's not something you're willing to try, then why did you bother posting your question?  For what it's worth, I was in the **exact** same boat as you 2 years ago.  I was developing PHP apps because they're cheap to run almost anywhere.  The particular code I was working on lended itself to using Node.js so I switched.  My customers went with me and were happy that they had a better product to use.  Reconsider your assumptions about your customers.

Comment: Sorry, my response was a little bitchy. I actually just realized that you answered my question. Just not in a way I expected.